# Insert values in list in DataFrame cell based on string in another cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, startswith

I have a pandas DataFrame df containing three columns where one is largely empty. In the first column I have a list of agreements where some of them have similar names. I want to insert a list of values in the empty column if the value in the agreements column starts with a certain string.

Example:

| Agreement | Alias |
| --- | --- |
| SampleAgreement | None |
| Agreement1 | None |
| Agreement2 | None |

I want to insert the aliases [Agree, agreement] in the Alias column for Agreement1 and Agreement2, like so:

| Agreement | Alias |
| --- | --- |
| SampleAgreement | None |
| Agreement1 | [Agree, agreement] |
| Agreement2 | [Agree, agreement] |

What I have tried:

```
df.loc[df['Agreement'].str.startswith('Agreement', na = False), 'Alias'] = pd.Series([['Agree, agreement']]*df.shape[0])
```

Problem is when I run the check to see if it worked, I get an empty DataFrame:

```
df[df['Alias'].str.startswith('Agreement', na = False)]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code can already set up the column `Alias` as you desire.  Just that your code for selecting it is not working.  You can simply print(df) to see it set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

use a regex with `^` which checks for a pattern at the start of a string.

```
df.loc[df['Agreement'].str.contains('^Agreement'),'Alias'] = [['Agree','Agreement']]

        Agreement               Alias
0  SampleAgreement                None
1       Agreement1  [Agree, Agreement]
2       Agreement2  [Agree, Agreement]
```

---

```
df['Agreement'].str.contains('^Agreement')
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: Agreement, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks, this did work fine! What if I want to add the name in Agreement in the Alias list as well in the same operation? The Alias column should then be for instance [Agreement1, Agree, Agreement]. 
I tried
= [[df['Agreement'], Agree, Agreement], but that included the entire column in the list.

Comment: @Andreas this is usually not recommended, why do you need a list ?

Comment: because the aliases can have more than one value, shouldn't you use a list then?

Comment: Sorry, I was in another meeting.

If the row matches the requirement, I want to insert Agree, Agreement and the name of the agreement in the Agreement column, pseudo code for this:

df.loc[df['Agreement'].str.contains('^Agreement'),'Alias'] = [[(GET name of agreement in the agreement column), 'Agree','Agreement']]

Answer (score 0):

Your code for generating the column `Alias` can already set it up with your desired output:

```
         Agreement               Alias
0  SampleAgreement                None
1       Agreement1  [Agree, agreement]
2       Agreement2  [Agree, agreement]
```

Your code that you run the check, i.e. `df[df['Alias'].str.startswith('Agreement', na = False)]`  isn't working because of 2 reasons:  1) the contents of column `Alias` is now a list of string (thus with square brackets) rather than simple string. Therefore, you cannot use `str.startswith()` to match it.   2) `Agreement` does not match `agreement` because of case sensitive match.

If you don't need it to be a list of string, you can set it up simply as follows:

```
df.loc[df['Agreement'].str.startswith('Agreement', na = False), 'Alias'] = 'Agree, agreement'
```

The output will then be :

```
         Agreement             Alias
0  SampleAgreement              None
1       Agreement1  Agree, agreement
2       Agreement2  Agree, agreement
```

In this case, you can check it with codes like:

```
import re
df[df['Alias'].str.contains('Agreement', flags=re.IGNORECASE)]

Output:

    Agreement             Alias
1  Agreement1  Agree, agreement
2  Agreement2  Agree, agreement
```

Here we used `flags=re.IGNORECASE` to make a case insensitive match.  We also use `str.contains()` instead of `str.startswith()` because `agreement` is not at the start of the string.